# Kendo ui Grid inline edit , field with editorTemplate

Tags: javascript, grid, kendo-ui

Kendo ui Grid inline edit field with editorTemplate how to get the event of button update ( when we create or update) in order to force refresh of page with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use the Events extension method of the Kendo grid...

```
.Events(events => events.Save("onSaveClicked").Cancel("onCancelClicked"))
```

And add javascript event handlers for corresponding events on the hosting or main page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function onSaveClicked()
{
    alert("Save Clicked!!!");
}
function onCancelClicked()
{
    alert("Cancel Clicked...");
}
</script>
```